# Does "\n" get immediately converted to a newline charachter in python?

Tags: python, string, matplotlib, newline

I'm using matplotlib, and I want to label something with `"$\nu$"`. I was getting errors, and I realized it was because matplotlib was interpreting the `\n` as a newline. Does python immediately convert any instances of `\n` to newlines whenever a string is created?

Comment: Yes, unless it'a a raw string (`r` prefix:  `r"$\nu$"` does *not* convert to a newline).  In a regular string, you can escape the backslash:  `"$\\nu$"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the Tutorial section on [Strings](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) and the reference documentation for [String and Bytes literals](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) explain, backslash escapes are interpreted in string literals.

This happens before matplotlib even gets to see anything; the literal `"$\nu$"` represents a string with a dollar sign, a newline, a u, and a dollar sign, and that string is the value matplotlib will see.

There are two ways to avoid this:

- Escape the backslash itself, as in `"$\\nu$"`.
- Use a raw string, as in `r"$\nu$"`.

Generally, when you're dealing with strings that have lots of backslashes (regular expressions, Windows pathnames, etc.), raw strings are more readable.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Except if you specified that it's a raw string:

```
r"$\nu$"
```

Another way around is to use double backslashes, escaping the backslash:

```
"$\\nu$"
```